# Подвал на сайте WP

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Есть подвал сайта,скопировал весь его код из файла footer.php.
Но почему-то он встал некорректно,в чем может быть проблема?заранее благодарю за ответы.

Архив с ссылками - https://yadi.sk/d/on7tE8gIxy7Gf

P.S. Репутации не хватает,чтобы ссылки вставить.а код не вставляется адекватно.

Comment: Можно подробнее, что и куда скопировали? Для чего? Что вы хотите получить в результате?

Зачем копировать код из footer.php если его достаточно подключить в новом шаблоне страницы `<?php get_footer(); ?>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

glav.php - если это шаблон будущей главной страницы, то называться он должен `page-glav.php` (стандартный шаблон page.php). В нем подключается

```
    <?php

      /*
        Template Name: Home Page
      */

      get_header();

    ?>

     <section>
      <div class="container">
       <div class="row">    
        <div class="col-sm-12" style="margin-bottom:25px;">
         <a   href="http://tiarsekj.bget.ru/shop/" class="button13">Общая категория</a>
        </div>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="container">
      <div class="row "  >

       <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6"  style="margin-left: 50px;margin-right: -120px;" id="cas">
        <a href="http://tiarsekj.bget.ru/product-category/casio/" class="ch">
         <div id="casio">
          <p><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br></p>
         </div>
        </a>
       </div>
       <div class=" col-xs-6 col-md-6" >
        <a href="http://tiarsekj.bget.ru/product-category/orient/" class="ch">
         <div id="orient">
          <p><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br></p>
         </div>
        </a>
       </div>

      </div>
     </div>
    </section>

    <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: В который раз вы меня выручаете,спасибо большое)
Только не пойму,а какая разница как называется файл главной страницы?

Comment: ну как бы есть определенные правила https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-files/ `page-{slug}.php`
The page slug template is used when visitors request a specific page, for example one with the “about” slug (page-about.php).

Comment: хм,нужно будет заняться прочитать,а то вслепую считай все делаю,благодарю еще раз)